# Setup AWS SES and incoming mail has \r\n truncated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ses

I've setup AWS SES to drop email into an S3 bucket, but when AWS saves the email, the \r\n line endings are truncated resulting in bad data.

So a line like:
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

appear as:
1.1.1.12.2.2.2

How do I fix this?

Upon further investigation, my email client (Yahoo! web browser and mail.com web browser) is doing this:

Take a look here:

```
X-Mailer: WebService/1.1.14680 YMailNorrin Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 516

------=_Part_1176366_1815233237.1573171750698
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

2.2.2.23.3.3.34.4.4.4

------=_Part_1176366_1815233237.1573171750698
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head></head><body><div class="yahoo-style-wrap" style="font-family:lucida console, sans-serif;font-size:16px;"><div>2.2.2.2</div><div>3.3.3.3</div><div>4.4.4.4</div><div><br></div></div></body></html>
------=_Part_1176366_1815233237.1573171750698--
```

The HTML portion is correct but the text portion isn't.
What's going on here?

Comment: I seriously doubt Amazon's SES is at fault here.  What are you using to look at the emails?  Have you looked at the file contents with a hex-editor or something that can show you unprintable characters?

Comment: Yes, vi in hex mode ... I'm sending mail from Yahoo! and mail.com and both have the same issue.